# If session expires, continue work after re-login

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, web, session-timeout

I have a problem regarding session timeout  in the following Scenario.

1. First, the user login with his valid information.
2. After successful login, he is redirected to "PAGE1"
3. He input some data and press "**NEXT PAGE button**" . Now, He will be redirected to "PAGE2". 
   The data input by the user in PAGE1 is stored in the session attribute. So that he may go back to PAGE1 from PAGE2 by using "**PREVIOUS PAGE button**" .
4. When he press "**UPDATE**" button , If the  session timeout occurs, Login page will be redirected.

So my Requirement is:
1. He should continue his work from the same page  if he successfully login without loosing           any previously set data in session attribute.
2. He should go back to PAGE1 if he want.

Is it possible? What can be the possible solutions for the given scenario?
I would be grateful for the suggestion.
Thankyou.

Comment: as a layman solution ,create a domain class to store the state of the user

Answer (score 1):

You could store the data input from page1 in hidden fields in your form on page2. That way page submits all the data from page1 and page2 so the server does not need to hold the response from page1 in the session.

This also allows the user to be filling out two form simultaneously in different tabs of their browser and reduces the amount of session data you're holding onto so could be considered preferable anyway.

I think you can then redirect after login with whatever request it was you received on the server when you discovered their session had timed out.